# Servicing ws:// in Node.js via Tomcat and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, node.js, socket

I've Googled various combinations of keywords but I cannot find a suitable description of what to do to get this to work. Currently, I have a web site running Apache 2 with everything except ports 80 and 443 blocked. I've set up Tomcat to route through :80 and :443 using:

`<Location /tomcat/>
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/tomcat/
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>`

Furthermore, existing Node.js http[s] apps have also been successfully routed via code like this:

`<Location /app_8201/>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8201/
</Location>`

I'm running Apache/2.2.15, Tomcat 6 and Node.js v0.10.26 on CentOS under Azure. Websocket support is present as running sample apps referring `localhost:9999` works OK. There looks as if there should be a `ProxyPass ws://localhost:9999`, but if I [follow the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111994/websocket-stopped-working-on-tomcat-7-0-50):

`<Location /ws/>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:9999
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:9999
</Location>`

I get an HTTP 500 error trying to access the directory `ws` by either `http` or `ws`.

I use `mod_proxy_ajp` instead of `mod_jk` as it is my understanding the `ajp` is "better".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebSocket support first appeared in Apache 2.4.5 through the mod_proxy_wstunnel module, there is no support in previous versions like Apache 2.2.

The protocol must be explicitly selected via ws:// or wss://, the AJP and HTTP protocol modules for mod_proxy don't know anything about WebSockets:

```
<Location /ws>
    ProxyPass ws://localhost:9999
    ProxyPassReverse ws://localhost:9999
</Location>
```